# Recibo vacío el form data cuando lo envío al servicio - React + .NET app - Error 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net, redux, formdata

Tengo una aplicación React+Redux con .Net en el back. Necesito enviar un Archivo a través de un Form Data. La testeé antes en PostMan y se envió ok, pero no tengo la misma suerte en la app, si debugueo el servicio .Net `attachmentXml` viene vacío.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

**Así configuré el form data:**

```
let formData = new FormData();
values.otherSupports && formData.append("attachmentXml", values.otherSupports)
```

**El método dispatch de redux, envío un 2 porque el servicio acepta 1, 2 o 3:**

```
dispatch(postSendDocumentXml(formData, 2))
```

**Este es el duck reducer:**

```
export const postSendDocumentXml = (formData, dtId) => {

    return {
        type: POST_DOCUMENT_XML,
        payload: {
            request: {
                headers: {
                    contentType: 'text/xml'
                },
                method: 'GET',
                url: `${BASE_ENDPOINT}Process/xml/${dtId}`,
                data: formData
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**El servicio .Net:**

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Process/xml/{documentType:int}")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessXMLAttachment([FromForm] IFormFile attachmentXml,  DocumentTypeEnum documentType)
        {
            if (attachmentXml == null || attachmentXml.Length == 0) return BadRequest("El xml es obligatorio");
            if (!_fileService.GetFileExtension(attachmentXml.FileName).ToLower().Equals("xml")) return BadRequest("El archivo debe ser un .xml válido");

            SPDocument doc = await  _documentService.GetDocumentFromXml(attachmentXml, documentType);
            return Ok(doc);
        }
```

**Error:**

> ErrI1rp Error: Request failed with status code 400
> at createError (createError.js:16:1)
> at settle (settle.js:17:1)
> at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)

**Axios:**

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create(axiosInit);
        axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function(config){
            return config;
        },function (error) {
            console.log('ErrI1rq',error)

            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        );

           axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(function (config) {
            return config;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('ErrI1rp',error)

               return Promise.reject(error);
        })
```

**Como pueden ver en Postman dio ok:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El primer valor es el archivo que necesito enviar, que lo obtengo del contexto de Formik, y el segundo los datos que envío finalmente, es decir, el archivo con su clave**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas en stackoverflow en español, si no traduces tu pregunta con el boton [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/550840/edit), te van a cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: gracias adrigo! ya lo cambié

Comment: Algo me dice que estás creando el objeto `FormData` antes de que el usuario haya seleccionado un archivo y, además, estás tratando de agregar el mismo objeto con `formData.append("attachmentXml",  formData)`. En lugar de ese segundo `formData`, debería ser la variable que contiene el archivo.

Comment: Triby, hice los cambios que me sugeriste, es cierto estaba mal el dato dentro de append(), lo modifiqué arriba, gracias. También, agregué una imagen con los datos que envío al servicio. Pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el componente del archivo y cómo defines el objeto `values` para saber qué es lo que hay en `values.otherSupports`

Comment: Finalmente, resolví mi problema agregando el archivo al `FormData` indicandole el índice, de la siguiente manera: `formData.append("name", file[0])`